# Undelete files in docker

Tags: docker, recovery

I have docker container and execute command

```
# rm -rf /etc/
rm: cannot remove '/etc/hosts': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/etc/resolv.conf': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/etc/hostname': Device or resource busy
```

How to recover deleted files and directories?

*UPD:* according to comment about https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91297/how-to-undelete-just-deleted-directory-with-rm-r-command

It doest not work for me beacause I have removed /etc/ directory and unable to install any additional software inside docker container.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91297/how-to-undelete-just-deleted-directory-with-rm-r-command

Comment: @Rao I have HDD not SSD

Comment: @Rao do you know how to migrate question on `unix.` ?

Comment: it appears only moderators can move a topic http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-migrate-questions-from-stackoverflow

Comment: @Rao do you know why people downvote?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not going to be able to recover them reliably without a backup which would most likely come in the form of a `docker commit` of the container or a snapshot of the underlying docker filesystem.

You can get the original `/etc` back from the image you started the container from though, which is at least better than where you are now.

```
docker run {your_image} tar -cf - /etc | docker exec {your_container_missing_etc} tar -xvf -
```

`{your_image}` being the image your container is running.

`{your_container_missing_etc}` being the `id` or `name` of the container missing `/etc`

Comment: Recreate container with loosing database was acceptable for me, so I did it, but thx for thoughts about recovering, I'll accept answer after week or two. Any way after this issue I had another one with write access from docker container solving which led to data corruption of data volume.